# OpenGL depth problem

Tags: opengl

I am drawing two cubes, first a red one and then a green one in front of the red one. When I rotate the camera I can see the green cube through the red cube.

[image: green cube behind red cube]

I have enabled depth test and I clear depth buffer. I'm using OpenGL 4.4 core profile and a simple diffuse shader by the way.

Comment: Could you show the code that does this?

Comment: Unfortunately it's encapsulated in several classes. It's a simple vertex array and element draw call.

Comment: "I have enabled depth test and I clear depth buffer." Are you sure?

Comment: I am sorry it was totally me. I was setting depth test only at the begining.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to the question, and accept it to mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `gl_Enable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` only at the beginning of my render process outside of the main loop so then I realized I should set this render state every frame before my render calls so I did it.

Example:

```
// main loop
while(true)
{
    // depth test
    gl_Enable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // render calls...
}
```